# How do I detect if a node has left the screen using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making a game, and I want to check if a node(the "player node") has left the screen.

There are 2 ways I thought of doing it:

1. Check the x and y coordinates, and see if they had exceeded those of the boundary, if they do, run gameOver().
2. Place a node just off screen, then if the player node comes in contact with that node, it runs gameOver().

I have no idea how I would do either of these so please . could someone help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the number of end points. If there are too many possible positions outside the screen, then check for the coordinates. If there are only a few, make sure they are nodes with a property noting for outside.

Comment: Thanks, but I am quite new to the language, so what would the code be?